# How to rename columns obtained by SQL INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite

I was reading the comparison of SQL and Pandas in the website
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html. Here when I was doing sql inner join the names of columns are repeated. How to give appropriate names to them?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
np.random.seed(100)


# database
con = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")


# dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                     'value': np.random.randn(4)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'D', 'E'],
                     'value': np.random.randn(4)})

print(df1, '\n\n', df2)

# add dataframes to database
df1.to_sql('df1',con,if_exists='replace',index=False)
df1.to_sql('df2',con,if_exists='replace',index=False)


q = """
SELECT *
FROM df1
INNER JOIN df2
  ON df1.key = df2.key;
"""
pd.read_sql_query(q,con)
```

This gives

```
 key     value key     value
0   B  0.342680   B  0.981321
1   D -0.252436   D  0.221180
2   D -0.252436   D  0.514219
```

How to get the table like:

```
    key   df1_value   df2_value
0   B  0.342680  0.981321
1   D -0.252436  0.514219
2   D -0.252436  0.221180
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `as`:

```
SELECT df1.key as key1, df1.value as df1_value, df2.value as df2_value
FROM df1 INNER JOIN 
     df2
     ON df1.key = df2.key;
```

Because the keys are the same, you don't need to include the values from both tables.

Comment: This is great only if we have few columns to rename, is there `for-loop` like techniques which will automatically do the job?

Comment: @MilkyWay007 . . . No.  That is not how SQL works.  You can generate the columns using a query or spreadsheet, though.  Or, you can even use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking since it was possible in python pandas, it might be possible in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to alias the column names. Instead of using the `SELECT *` construct, you want to specifiy which column you want to return, and use the `as` keyword to choose the display name of the column in the result set.

For more information, see [the sqlite documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm)

```
SELECT 
    df1.key,
    df1.value as df1_value,
    df2.value as df2_value
FROM df1
INNER JOIN df2
    ON df1.key = df2.key
```